# net maui "Submit form"/execute button after last element has been entered

Tags: .net, forms, maui, soft-keyboard

I have an entry on my page. When the user presses the "Ok"-button on the keyboard, the keyboard hides and nothing more is happening.

I have a button below that entry (continue). I want the button clicked method to be executed when the user presses ok on the keyboard on the last entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The **Completed** event is raised when the user has ended input by pressing the return key on the keyboard, or by pressing the Tab key on Windows. The handler for the event is a generic event handler* (.NET MAUI Official Documentation):

```
void OnEntryCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string text = ((Entry)sender).Text;
}
```

1. Let's assume that you've got an Entry and a Button (that says something like "Continue"). You'll set them up in your XAML file with names so you can refer to them in your code. It'll look something like this:

```
<Entry x:Name="myEntry" Placeholder="Type whatever you want..." Completed="OnEntryCompleted"/>
<Button x:Name="continueButton" Text="Continue" Clicked="OnContinueClicked"/>
```

2. Handle Entry's Completed Event: In your code-behind (e.g., MainPage.xaml.cs), create the OnEntryCompleted method to handle the Completed event of the Entry. Inside this method, you can programmatically invoke the click event handler of the continue button.

```
private void OnEntryCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OnContinueClicked(continueButton, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

3. Button Click Handler: Ensure you have a method handling the button's Clicked event.

```
private void OnContinueClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Logic to execute when continue button is clicked or entry is completed
}
```